# Johnson trotter permutation algorithm code in C++ language

Tags: c++

I am trying to implement Johnson trotter in C++ but I am stuck with normal permutation. I don't want to use vectors and want to create a class to solve this.

Could anyone help to with a C++ implementation of this?

```
void swap(int x, int y)
{
    int temp = arr[x];
    arr[x] = arr[y];
    arr[y] = temp;
    return;
}

void print(int s)
{
    for (int i = 0; i<s; i++)
        cout << arr[i] << " ";
    cout << endl;
    return;
}

void permute(int k, int s)
{
    if (k == 0)
        print(s);
    else
    {
        for (int i = k - 1; i >= 0; i--)
        {
            swap(i, k - 1);
            permute(k - 1, s);
            swap(i, k - 1);
        }
    }
}

int num(int x)
{
    int j = 0;
    if (x == 0)
        j = 1;
    else
        j = x*(num(x - 1));
    return j;
}
```

Comment: Do you know there is `std::next_permutation` (and also `std::swap`) ?

Comment: BTW, state clearly your problem. Do you have compile error ? unexpected output ? so which one (with which input ?).

Comment: I am able to get a permutation of numbers but not getting it in Johnson's trotter permutation. for example for n=3 I am not getting in this order:

[ 1 2 3 ] 
 [ 1 3 2 ] 
[ 3 1 2 ] 
 [ 3 2 1 ] 
 [ 2 3 1] 
[2 1 3]

Comment: Which algorithm do you follow, your doesn't look as the one there: [Trotter_algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Steinhaus%E2%80%93Johnson%E2%80%93Trotter_algorithm)

Answer (score 0):

I got a clear understanding of Trotter's algorithm here: https://youtu.be/xsFKorZ95Yw.

I created a vector to represent directions of numbers, -1 for left direction and 1 for right. In this implementation I sorted elements by ascending order and used -1 for initial directions.

```
template <typename T>
std::vector<int> PreparePermutation(std::vector<T>& input) {
  std::sort(input.begin(), input.end());
  std::vector<int> directions(input.size(), -1);
  return directions;
}

template <typename T>
bool NextPermutation(std::vector<T>& input, std::vector<int>& directions) {
  // position of max mobile number
  int max_mobile_pos = -1;
  for (int i = 0; i < input.size(); ++i) {
    // i - 1 or i + 1 to get left or right element it points to
    int pointed_pos = i + directions[i];
    // an element is mobile if it is larger than the element it points to
    if (pointed_pos >= 0 && pointed_pos < input.size() &&
        input[i] > input[pointed_pos]) {
      // find largest mobile element
      if (max_mobile_pos < 0 || input[i] > input[max_mobile_pos]) {
        max_mobile_pos = i;
      }
    }
  }
  if (max_mobile_pos == -1) {
    return false;
  }
  auto max_mobile_pointed_pos = max_mobile_pos + directions[max_mobile_pos];
  std::swap(input[max_mobile_pos], input[max_mobile_pointed_pos]);
  std::swap(directions[max_mobile_pos], directions[max_mobile_pointed_pos]);
  max_mobile_pos = max_mobile_pointed_pos;
  for (int i = 0; i < input.size(); ++i) {
    // flip direction of elements larger than current max mobile
    if (input[i] > input[max_mobile_pos]) {
      directions[i] *= -1;
    }
  }
  return true;
}
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).